# Launch chrome as an emulator using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a website where editors write articles using a custom built CMS. Once done they generally test these articles on desktop, but not mobile. To fix this I was wondering if there is an easy way to launch chrome using html/javascript such that I can provide it a url and one of the device emulators? (Keep in mind these are non tech people, and would be easily confused if I asked them to emulate themselves). If thats not possible then launch chrome in a new tab with specific width and height (which matches a mobile device)? Also if possible I would prefer these new windows to be incognito so that I do not save cookies in their sessions. Is there any way to do this? Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks for reading

Comment: There is a bookmarklet for chrome that allows you to view the different screen sizes (http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/). You might want to take a look at it.

Comment: Chrome has a "device mode" that is exactly what you need.  You can get to it through the developer tools window, or press ctrl-shift-M.  But there is  no way (AFAIK) to launch chrome already in that mode.  Docs here:  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Provides Device Emulator as shown in below screenshot. by pressing the f12 ( Developers tool ) you can find the option. by selecting that "Device Emulator" Icon. You can choose the device as shown in below screenshot and change the device Os and device type and resolution and Orientation.

[image]

[image]